# Get the documentdata from a webbrowser control in another application

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, hook

I'm looking for a way to get the document information (or document text) from another applications webbrowser control (and possibly alter it).
The other application is written in .net, but not by me.

I'm looking for an ability like this:

- I would like an eventhandler for the OnDocumentCompleted that can get me the information of that document.
- If possible, i would also like to intercept certain pages, add some html, and send them back to the second app to be displayed.

Searching the web pointed me towards using 'Hooks', but not much is found using hooks in this situation.

Hope you can help me out
Anthony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code provides an example of html parsing that returns plain text (
the parsing depends on page content).

```
private string GetPlainText(WebBrowser webBrowser)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     // Pick out a heading.
    foreach (HtmlElement h1 in webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("H1"))
        sb.Append(h1.InnerText + ". ");

    // Select only some text, ignoring everything else.
    foreach (HtmlElement div in webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("DIV"))
        if (div.GetAttribute("classname") == "story-body")
            foreach (HtmlElement p in div.GetElementsByTagName("P"))
            {
              string classname = p.GetAttribute("classname");
              if (classname == "introduction" || classname == "") sb.Append(p.InnerText + " ");
            }
    return sb.ToString();
  }
}
```